# Shareable link error for publishing TensorFlow Embedding Projector online through gist

Tags: json, tensorflow, pca, gist

http://projector.tensorflow.org/ allows you to publish and share your own visualizations if you click "publish" and link to your own .json config gist w/ path to your own data. However, I'm getting an error when I link it to my gist .json config file as the instructions dictate (https://gist.github.com/jmolayem/2a28b68807602e4c3c8fa9987c1d08a6):

```
{
  "embeddings": [
    {
      "tensorName": "My tensor",
      "tensorShape": [
        1000,
        50
      ],
      "tensorPath": "https://gist.github.com/jmolayem/2a28b68807602e4c3c8fa9987c1d08a6#file-test55-tsv"
    }
  ]
}
```

My hunch is the tensorShape has to match the .tsv file. But if that were true, I don't understand why the direct upload of the .tsv file works in the demo but not when I publish.

Am I missing something in formatting the gist file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close! Your `tensorPath` doesn't point to the raw tsv file, but to an html page showing a snippet of that file, along other files.

If you click on the `raw` button on the top left of the `test55.tsv` snippet, you will get
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jmolayem/2a28b68807602e4c3c8fa9987c1d08a6/raw/15252f862a318b8b11e550bdf2bfddb3991f4cab/test55.tsv

which you should use as a `tensorPath`.